# Помогите написать handler aiogram 3.1.1 Successful Payment

Tags: python, aiogram

Мне нужно зарегистрировать хендлер на успешную оплату на aiogram 3.1.1

```
dp.message.register(selamo.recruit_balance_sum, SelectAmount.GET_RECRUIT_BALANCE)
dp.pre_checkout_query.register(selamo.pre_checkout_query)
dp.message.register(selamo.successful_payment, ContentType.SUCCESSFUL_PAYMENT)
```

Вот такой блок кода и в 3 строчке нужно добавить корректную проверку на тип
Через MagicFilter(F) не нашел, ContentType.SUCCESSFUL_PAYMENT не работает

Answer (score -1):

не совсем понял вопроса, но предположим, что вы хотите добавить корректную проверку на тип сообщения в хендлере aiogram для успешной оплаты (ContentType.SUCCESSFUL_PAYMENT). тут нужно использовать `MessageHandler` с фильтром

```py
from aiogram import types
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Command

# ...

@dp.message_handler(Command("recruit_balance_sum"), content_types=[types.ContentType.SUCCESSFUL_PAYMENT])
async def successful_payment_handler(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    # ...
    await message.answer("оплата прошла")
```

тут используется `MessageHandler` с фильтром `content_types`, который ожидает только сообщения с типом `SUCCESSFUL_PAYMENT`, так этот хендлер будет вызван только в случае успешной оплаты